# Section title and the first paragraph on the same line

Tags: sectioning, context

This question is about ConTeXt not LaTeX.

I'd like to have a special section such that A) there is no line break after a section title, and B) paragraphs in the section is narrower and indented like so:

```
Title   Paragraph 1, Paragraph 2,
        Paragraph 3, Paragraph 4,
        and Paragraph 5
```

So far I have this:

```
\setupnarrower[left=4cm]
\definehead[special][section]
\setuphead[special]
    [number=no,
     textstyle=\tfd,
     beforesection={\startnarrower[left]},
     aftersection=\stopnarrower]

\starttext

\startspecial[title=Knuth]
\input knuth
\stopspecial

\startsection[title=Lorem]
\input lorem
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

This achieves the second goal but not the first: [image]

Ideally, top/cap height of the title (Knuth) and top/cap height of the first paragraph ("Thus, I came ...") are (roughly) vertically aligned, not their baselines.
Could anyone suggest a way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable (including documentclass and all includes needed to acquire your output).

Comment: @Skillmon, Thank you for your comment. I've fixed MWE, so it is now compilable. That said this question is about ConTeXt not about LaTeX.

Comment: Oh, I missed that point... Sorry but I can't help you with that.then.

Comment: I'm not sure I get how you want things to look. What if the title is long (like five to six words). How do you want it to look then?

Comment: I am looking for this formatting in a limited use case, and the section titles are always one word in my use case. As such I am not really interested in extending this look to longer titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `after={\blank[overlay]}`.

```
\setupnarrower[left=4cm]

\definehead
  [special][section]

\setuphead
  [special]
  [
    number=no,
    after={\blank[overlay]},
    textstyle=\tfd,
    beforesection={\startnarrower[left]},
    aftersection=\stopnarrower,
  ]

\starttext

\startspecial[title=Knuth]
\input knuth
\stopspecial

\startsection[title=Lorem]
\input lorem
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

To align the top of the line with the top of the title you can use this (dodgy) construction.  I tested it with a few different fontsizes and it seems to work but I don’t give any guarantee.  Also it breaks gridsnapping.

```
\setupnarrower[left=4cm]

\definehead
  [special][section]

\setuphead
  [special]
  [
    number=no,
    after={\blank[overlay,halfline]},
    textcommand=\tbox,
    textstyle=\tfd,
    beforesection={\startnarrower[left]},
    aftersection=\stopnarrower,
  ]

\starttext

\startspecial[title=Knuth]
\input knuth
\stopspecial

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your second approach achieves the desired effect. I am not using grid-based layout, so breaking gridsnapping is not an issue in my use case.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `description` environment:

```
\definedescription
    [special]
    [
      alternative=left,
      width=4cm,
      headstyle=\tfd,
      headcommand=\tbox,
    ]

\starttext

\startspecial[title=Knuth]
\input knuth
\stopspecial

\startsection[title=Lorem]
\input lorem
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]